# Error 10053 using composer

Tags: windows-7, command-line, php, wamp

I need to use Composer in my wamp server on a windows 7 machine but I keep on getting a 10053 error.

For example when I try to install laravel I get the following message:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/p/laravel/laravel$9339d274502c834391a2639c180a
709e6091260b12eea0d9735f85fbbad31b41.json" file could not be downloaded: 
send of 103 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established 
connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

SSL is enabled in both php.ini files.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your windows rather than with composer

Comment: Agree, but please help me figure this out. I don't know where to begin. tnx

Comment: Googling the error message yields http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204594

Comment: Thanks, I did come across that one but it didn't help me. I'll try again.

Comment: I am moving this to SuperUser since it doesn't seem to be about programming.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?